# I am getting this error in react js -- src\components\Allcourse.js Line 20:35: 'course' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Course from './Course';

const Allcourse = () => {
  const [courses, setCourse] = useState([
    { title: 'java course', description: 'this is demo' },
    { title: 'react course', description: 'this is demo' },
    { title: 'django course', description: 'this is demo' },
  ]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>All course</h1>
      <p>list of courses</p>

      {courses.length > 0
        ? courses.map(item => <Course course={item} />)
        : 'No course'}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Allcourse;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your code to reproduce the error. And from what I see you may be importing your Course component wrong. Double check your file path and make sure the naming is all correct.

Here a codesandbox to reference:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-flower-1p160?file=/src/App.js

Comment: {
                courses.length>0? courses.map((item)=> <Course course={item} />)
                : "No course"
            }

Comment: Yes that looks correct. What do your import statements look like at the top of your file?